# generating sequence from a particular number in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate programming ,  I am using annotations

@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="empid_generator", sequenceName="emp_id")

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="empid_generator")

@Column(name="empid")
private int empid;
```

this is my id field in bean class . The default sequence created by hibernate is starting from 50 . but i want the sequence to be started from 70000 .how to achieve this??

Comment: When you define your sequence in your database, initialize it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="empid_generator", sequenceName="emp_id", initialValue=70000)
```

See javadoc for other attributes you can set: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html